# Compiling FFTW3 for IOS 5.1 on OSX 10.7

Tags: ios, xcode4, signal-processing, fftw

A similar version of this question has been asked before ([how to compile fftw3 on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850624/how-to-compile-fftw3-on-ios)) about previous versions of IOS and/or OSX, but I am unable to get fftw3 working on a actual IOS device. (Though it works fine in the simulator using the MacPorts "universal" distribution). If anyone has had any success using fftw3 please let me know how you were able to get it working! I am using OSX 10.7 and am trying specifically to run fftw on an iPad3 with IOS 5.1 installed. Thanks.

Comment: Why not use the iOS Accelerate framework instead?  It's supposed to have around the same performance or better for common FFT types.

Comment: Hi, fftw is more commonly used and I am already familiar with it. The Accelerate framework is a bit confusing, especially for packing a 2D image into the appropriate data representation. I suppose I'll have to learn more about it if I can't get fftw3 working!

Comment: Ok, I've given up on trying to compile fftw3 for ios, at least for now. I've gotten good results using the Accelerate framework for 2D FFTs, although I'm still having some issues with non-power-of-two images and also their autocorrelate function seems to be missing. But if anyone's interested in this maybe you can comment on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708667/using-ios-accelerate-framework-for-2d-signal-processing.